# Variation of summary in R

Tags: r

Being new to R, I want to show different summaries of my data set. Using the simple

```
 summary(myData)
```

just gives the frequencies of the each variable for each column, which isn't that useful.

What can I do to display the same table summary, but for something other than frequencies? For example, percentages?

All of my columns contain finite, discrete variables.

Comment: You might want to look at `?prop.table`

Comment: For a quick summary that includes frequencies, check out `describe` from the `Hmisc` package: `describe(myData)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick summary that includes frequencies, check out `describe` from the Hmisc package: `describe(myData)`

You can also use `sapply` to run the `prop.table` function (as @RichardScriven proposed) on each categorical variable in your data frame. For example:

```
data(Arthritis, package="vcd") # Data frame with some categorical columns

# Function to identify and summarize categorical variables in a data frame.
# If some of your categorical columns have a large number of categories, 
# you can modify this function to only summarize columns with, say, 10 or
# fewer categories, or something like that.
catSummary = function(df) {

  # Identify categorical variables
  catVars = names(df)[sapply(df, function(var) {is.factor(var)|is.character(var)})] 

  # Make summary tables
  sapply(df[,catVars], function(x) {
    round(prop.table(table(x, dnn=NULL))*100,1)
  })
}

# Run the summary function
catSummary(Arthritis)

$Treatment
Placebo Treated 
51.2    48.8 

$Sex
Female   Male 
70.2   29.8 

$Improved
None   Some Marked 
50.0   16.7   33.3
```

Comment: since data.frames are also lists, you can also use `lapply(Arthritis, SummaryFun)`

Comment: Yes, but then the `SummaryFun` gets applied to every column, even, in this case, non-categorical ones. However, I've updated my code to select categorical variables first and then use `sapply` on the resulting data frame subset, which I think captures the spirit of your comment.